# android listview background not changing on swipe

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, swipe, android-background

I've setup swipe list view with https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview. It does provide various event listeners to handle swipe related events.

Everything works perfectly except one thing.

I want to change background color of swiped list item only. It revert back once it gets back.

[image]

I can do this with **tap** event from adapter. I could've used list adapter to do this but since I want to change background on **swipe left** (listener ) only, I can not use adapter.  So doing this from adapter might not work.

Following listeners work for me -

```
swipeListView.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {       
         View v = swipeListView.getChildAt(position);
         swipeListView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

         ci = u_items.get(position); // getter of list item data

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ci.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(int position, boolean fromRight) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onListChanged() {
    }

    . // other listeners
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

This does not throw any error or warning but I can't see background being changed. *Toast* does show up so *swipe left listener* is actually working.

Perhaps, I'm doing something wrong while setting background itself. Not sure what. Since, *swipelistview* is custom view that extends **ListView** I can't imagine how to do this from that listener only.

Even, I could've used android list selection to set background color in XML file but it works with tap listener only. So this option is also eliminated.Other than this everything else works so perfect.

A push in right direction would be good. If any code is needed further to analyze I can edit question.

Comment: I also tried to setup the code u found on this link  https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview, but dont know from where to proceed

Answer (score 1):

you already defined v so you can use it better for you and easier.

```
View v = swipeListView.getChildAt(position);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
```

Comment: yes. I was going to remove that `View v ...` as it's unnecessary. But that doesn't work either.

Comment: try replacing swipeListView for this .. this.getchildxxx

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by obtaining the background view and changing it that way. I used the onStartOpen method instead of the onOpen method.

```
@Override
public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {
    View v = mSwipeListView.getChildAt(position);
        if (v == null) return;

        if (right) { // nothing

        } else {
            final ImageView mCurrImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
            mCurrShareImage.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where this method must be implement?

Comment: onStartOpen is a method in BaseSwipeListViewListener.  In my case it's implemented in the fragment in which I use the SwipeListView.

    mSwipeListView.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {

...
        @Override
        public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {